# How to use XPath to extract first three sentences from a paragraph?

Tags: xpath

I need to scrape the first three sentences from a paragraph, if they exist, using XPath.

I've already isolated the paragraph I want using:

```
//h3[contains(., 'Synopsis')]/following-sibling::p[1]
```

Which returns a plain, unformatted paragraph:

```
What do we do when the world's walls - its family structures, its value-systems, it political forms - crumble? The central character of this novel, 'Moor' Zogoiby, only son of a wealthy, artistic-bohemian Bombay family, finds himself in such a moment of crisis. His mother, a famous painter and an emotional despot, worships beauty, but Moor is ugly, he has a deformed hand. Moor falls in love, with a married woman; when their secret is revealed, both are expelled; a suicide pact is proposed, but only the woman dies. Moor chooses to accept his fate, plunges into a life of depravity in Bombay, then becomes embroiled in a major financial scandal. The novel ends in Spain, in the studio of a painter who was a lover of Moor's mother: in a violent climax Moor has, one more, to decide whether to save the life of his lover by sacrificing his own.
```

I only want the first three sentences, and I'm willing to be lenient and ignore that first question mark, I just want whatever comes before the first three periods.

Comment: What's your input XML (please edit the post and not post it as comment)?

Answer (score 0):

```
concat(
  substring-before(//h3[contains(., 'Synopsis')]/following-sibling::p[1]/text(), '.'),
  '.',
  substring-before(substring-after(//h3[contains(., 'Synopsis')]/following-sibling::p[1]/text(), '.'), '.'),
  '.',
  substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(//h3[contains(., 'Synopsis')]/following-sibling::p[1]/text(), '.'), '.'), '.'),
  '.'
)
```

(It's fun to do crazy things with XPath, but in real-life scenarios I wouldn't use it for tasks like this unless forced to it by absolute lack of other possibilities.)